# How to monitor IIS worker process using Windows performance monitor

Tags: iis, iis-8, application-pool, iis-8.5, perfmon

I have an asp.net mvc application deployed in IIS. Sometimes its application pool worker process hangs so I would like to know if there is a way to monitor a specific IIS worker process using windows performance monitor?  If so, what indicators I have to monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, we could add counter in the process monitor to figure out the Process identifier of the process.

You could right click the performance window and select counter.

[image]

Then you could choose the was_w3wp and select the process id w3wp process.

[image]